# Error Importing bacpac from Azure to local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm trying to import a bacpac from Azure to a local SQL Server 2012 database. I get this error at the end of the process:

> SQL72012 Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box...
>
> Could not allocate space for object ‘’ in database ‘’ because the ‘PRIMARY’ filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Comment: As the error indicates,you are seeing space crunch  issues.See the size of database in Azure and see if you are having space in local

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have enough space in local ;)

Comment: Check your file growth setting, maybe file growth is set to the % of current size and therefore cannot grow by the that amount..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. Upgrading from MSSQL Server Express to Developer solved the problem for me.